# res.tukey_hsd Could not convert ['AAAAAAAAA' '1_year1_year1_year2_year2_year2_year3_year3_year3_year'] to numeric

Tags: python, anova

I am trying to follow through on the analysis of Two-Way Anova from [**Here**](https://www.reneshbedre.com/blog/anova.html), which is similar to my case of data. Everything seems to work fine with the code provided, but when I implement **res.tukey_hsd** from the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from bioinfokit.analys import stat
d = pd.read_csv("https://reneshbedre.github.io/assets/posts/anova/twowayanova.txt", sep="\t")

d_melt = pd.melt(d, id_vars=['Genotype'], value_vars=['1_year', '2_year', '3_year'])
# replace column names
d_melt.columns = ['Genotype', 'years', 'value']
d_melt.head()

# perform multiple pairwise comparison (Tukey HSD)
# unequal sample size data, tukey_hsd uses Tukey-Kramer test
res = stat()
# for main effect Genotype
res.tukey_hsd(df=d_melt, res_var='value', xfac_var='Genotype', anova_model='value~C(Genotype)+C(years)+C(Genotype):C(years)')
res.tukey_summary
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: Could not convert ['AAAAAAAAA' '1_year1_year1_year2_year2_year2_year3_year3_year3_year'] to numeric
```

I am requesting help. What is wrong with the code and how can I execute it correctly?

A much more detail of the error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:1680, in _ensure_numeric(x)
   1679 try:
-> 1680     x = x.astype(np.complex128)
   1681 except (TypeError, ValueError):

ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:1683, in _ensure_numeric(x)
   1682 try:
-> 1683     x = x.astype(np.float64)
   1684 except ValueError as err:
   1685     # GH#29941 we get here with object arrays containing strs

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'AAAAAAAAA'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 17
     15 res = stat()
     16 # for main effect Genotype
---> 17 res.tukey_hsd(df=d_melt, res_var='value', xfac_var='Genotype', anova_model='value~C(Genotype)+C(years)+C(Genotype):C(years)')
     18 res.tukey_summary

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\bioinfokit\analys.py:882, in stat.tukey_hsd(self, df, res_var, xfac_var, anova_model, phalpha, ss_typ)
    878 group_pval = dict()
    879 # group_let = dict()
    880 # share_let = dict()
--> 882 mult_group, mult_group_count, sample_size_r = analys_general.get_list_from_df(df, xfac_var, res_var, 'get_dict')
    884 # self.anova_stat(df, res_var, anova_xfac_var)
    885 self.anova_stat(df, anova_model, ss_typ)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\bioinfokit\analys.py:421, in analys_general.get_list_from_df(df, xfac_var, res_var, funct)
    419             df_counts += 1
    420         elif funct == 'get_dict':
--> 421             mult_group[ele] = df[df[xfac_var] == ele].mean().loc[res_var]
    422             mult_group_count[ele] = df[df[xfac_var] == ele].shape[0]
    423 elif isinstance(xfac_var, list) and len(xfac_var) > 3:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:11556, in NDFrame._add_numeric_operations.<locals>.mean(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11539 @doc(
  11540     _num_doc,
  11541     desc="Return the mean of the values over the requested axis.",
   (...)
  11554     **kwargs,
  11555 ):
> 11556     return NDFrame.mean(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:11201, in NDFrame.mean(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11194 def mean(
  11195     self,
  11196     axis: Axis | None = 0,
   (...)
  11199     **kwargs,
  11200 ) -> Series | float:
> 11201     return self._stat_function(
  11202         "mean", nanops.nanmean, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs
  11203     )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:11158, in NDFrame._stat_function(self, name, func, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11154     nv.validate_stat_func((), kwargs, fname=name)
  11156 validate_bool_kwarg(skipna, "skipna", none_allowed=False)
> 11158 return self._reduce(
  11159     func, name=name, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, numeric_only=numeric_only
  11160 )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:10519, in DataFrame._reduce(self, op, name, axis, skipna, numeric_only, filter_type, **kwds)
  10515     df = df.T
  10517 # After possibly _get_data and transposing, we are now in the
  10518 #  simple case where we can use BlockManager.reduce
> 10519 res = df._mgr.reduce(blk_func)
  10520 out = df._constructor(res).iloc[0]
  10521 if out_dtype is not None:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:1534, in BlockManager.reduce(self, func)
   1532 res_blocks: list[Block] = []
   1533 for blk in self.blocks:
-> 1534     nbs = blk.reduce(func)
   1535     res_blocks.extend(nbs)
   1537 index = Index([None])  # placeholder

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:339, in Block.reduce(self, func)
    333 @final
    334 def reduce(self, func) -> list[Block]:
    335     # We will apply the function and reshape the result into a single-row
    336     #  Block with the same mgr_locs; squeezing will be done at a higher level
    337     assert self.ndim == 2
--> 339     result = func(self.values)
    341     if self.values.ndim == 1:
    342         # TODO(EA2D): special case not needed with 2D EAs
    343         res_values = np.array([[result]])

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:10482, in DataFrame._reduce.<locals>.blk_func(values, axis)
  10480     return values._reduce(name, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
  10481 else:
> 10482     return op(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:96, in disallow.__call__.<locals>._f(*args, **kwargs)
     94 try:
     95     with np.errstate(invalid="ignore"):
---> 96         return f(*args, **kwargs)
     97 except ValueError as e:
     98     # we want to transform an object array
     99     # ValueError message to the more typical TypeError
    100     # e.g. this is normally a disallowed function on
    101     # object arrays that contain strings
    102     if is_object_dtype(args[0]):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:158, in bottleneck_switch.__call__.<locals>.f(values, axis, skipna, **kwds)
    156         result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    157 else:
--> 158     result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    160 return result

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:421, in _datetimelike_compat.<locals>.new_func(values, axis, skipna, mask, **kwargs)
    418 if datetimelike and mask is None:
    419     mask = isna(values)
--> 421 result = func(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, mask=mask, **kwargs)
    423 if datetimelike:
    424     result = _wrap_results(result, orig_values.dtype, fill_value=iNaT)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:727, in nanmean(values, axis, skipna, mask)
    724     dtype_count = dtype
    726 count = _get_counts(values.shape, mask, axis, dtype=dtype_count)
--> 727 the_sum = _ensure_numeric(values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum))
    729 if axis is not None and getattr(the_sum, "ndim", False):
    730     count = cast(np.ndarray, count)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:1686, in _ensure_numeric(x)
   1683         x = x.astype(np.float64)
   1684     except ValueError as err:
   1685         # GH#29941 we get here with object arrays containing strs
-> 1686         raise TypeError(f"Could not convert {x} to numeric") from err
   1687 else:
   1688     if not np.any(np.imag(x)):

TypeError: Could not convert ['AAAAAAAAA' '1_year1_year1_year2_year2_year2_year3_year3_year3_year'] to numeric
```

Comment: what numerical result do you expect when converting `['AAAAAAAAA' '1_year1_year1_year2_year2_year2_year3_year3_year3_year']` to numeric?

Comment: @ Sembei Norimaki 
I did not convert to numeric rather that is the main error that I am seeking to resolve

Comment: Note that, the d_melt is a DataFrame with Genotype,years and value as columns.The codes are the one provided in [here](https://pypi.org/project/bioinfokit/) in the Tukey HSD test working example it will open [this](https://www.reneshbedre.com/blog/anova.html)  in this blog on the two-way Anova example the codes on Multiple pairwise comparisons (Post-hoc test) are the one i can't run as provided

Answer (score 0):

Check the data types of your DataFrame columns. You can do this using the dtypes attribute of the DataFrame:

```
print(d_melt.dtypes)
```

You can also convert value column to numeric type, non-numeric values will be converted to Nan.

```
d_melt['value'] = pd.to_numeric(d_melt['value'], errors='coerce')
```

You can also simplify anova string.

```
res.tukey_hsd(df=d_melt, res_var='value', xfac_var='Genotype', anova_model='value~C(Genotype)+C(years)')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still shows the same error  print(d_melt.dtypes)
gives:
Genotype:     object
years        object
value       float64
dtype: object

The column value is a float and there is no any missing value or np.nan on d_melt

Comment: @Fulgence updated

Comment: still I cant run it reproduce the same error , when use ur sugested res.tukey_hsd(....). i can't figure out what is wrong still